# Python - Gherkin Step conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, cucumber, gherkin, python-behave

I have a list with: (converted to a list after reading a .feature file)

```
Given Device unit of measure is set to value "<uom>"

And Device is set to value "Disabled"

And Device is set to value "<time>"

 Examples:

    | time | uom |

    | 1    | kpa |

    | 2    | kpa |

    | 3    | kpa |

    | 4    | kpa |

    | 5    | kpa |

    | 10   | kpa |

    | 15   | kpa |

    | 30   | kpa |

    | 60   | kpa |

    | 90   | kpa |
```

I am trying to convert it to:

Iteration 1:

```
Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"

And Device is set to value "Disabled"

And Device is set to value "1"
```

Iteration 2:

```
Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"

And Device is set to value "Disabled"

And Device is set to value "2"
```

and so on... Should have 10 iterations at the end with each of the value substituted.

I know when running behave tests, behave does this for you, but I am trying to get these steps stored in a database for future reference.

**Question is how can I convert the gherkin steps to the iterations I have shown above, using python?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what's your question or problem?

Comment: Updated the original. Thanks!

Comment: Examples must be use by Scenario outline.   https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial04.html

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. basically broke it apart piece by piece.

parsing the scenario/scenario outline
parsing the examples
Piecing back together the steps